# How to set up a callback function when an Exception occurs?

Tags: c, exception, assembly, cortex-m

I've been stuck for a while on how to set up a callback when an exception occurs.

I have this test code:

```
void main()
{
    long * bad = (long*)0x0A000000; //Invalid address

    //When the following line gets executed 
    //it causes an error and the debugger sends me to an assembly file. 
    *bad = 123456789; 
}
```

The assembly file that I am sent to looks like this(fragment of the real file):

```
.macro DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER name=
  .thumb_func
  .weak \name
\name:
1: b 1b /* endless loop */
.endm

DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER SRC_IRQHandler   /*Debugger stops on this line*/
```

As I understand DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER is a macro that defines an endless loop.
What I want to do is define my own function in a C file, that I could call when an exception occurs, instead of calling whats defined in the DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER macro.

My question is, How would I define a macro, in that assembly, that calls an specific C function?

Hopefully I explained myself. Any information or direction around this topic is appreciated.

In case it's relevant I am using GCC ARM compiler v5.4_2016q3

Thanks,
Isaac

EDIT

I am using a Cortex-M3.

Until now I realized I was talking about processor exceptions. According to the datasheet there is a list with 16 exception types.

Apparently, the way it works is that all the exception types are being redirected to the macro, which in turn calls some thumb function and afterwards an endless loop(according to DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER above in code).

What I would like to do is define my own function in a C file, for convenience, so every time any type of processor exception appear, I could control how to proceed.

Comment: C does nmoit support exceptions.

Comment: yep, but there *are* processor exceptions/traps/... seems to be about something like this. I think some clarification is needed, e.g. the exact platform and compiler/runtime used.

Comment: Although C does not support exception, specific environments provide extensions to support them. avr-gcc does, for instance. The answer to the question probably lies in the documentation of the support of the specific platform by the specific compiler in use. As a quick hint, it looks like the service routine is defined as a weak symbol, so probably you have some macros somewhere that will help you define your own handler that will have the same symbol name, so the linker or the init code installs it instead of the default one.

Comment: It depends on your OS.  Most OSes will turn these into traps or signals that you can catch (with signal or a structured exception handler).  On 'bare metal', you need to set up your own interrupt handler.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: As it seems there is most likely no OS. That seems to be a bare metal system. However, there is not enough/unclear information given.

Comment: Not clear what you want. Why do you think you need a macro? What do you try to do? Why assembly? … Read [ask] and provide the required information. As a sidenote: we are not a consulting service. Read the datasheets/reference manuals of your devices. And check the ARM documentation. It is all available freely online.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's comments, until now I realized I am talking about Cortex-M3 processor exceptions. I edited the question with more information. @Olaf: My intention is to look for directions and not to use this site as a consulting service to look for a concrete and final answer. I am trying to understand the documentation and what I am trying to do at the same time. Before posting this I was kind of lost, now I think I could keep on the research.

Comment: I haven't used an M3 specifically, but the first several bytes of your binary file should contain the memory address of the exception/interrupt handlers. The values that go here come from some file you're probably including/linking in. It looks like you're not programming bare-metal from scratch; it would help to provide information about which micro vendor you're using (for example, STM has a code generator that spits out interrupt handler definitions) and/or RTOS.

Comment: You need to more specific than then just Cortex-M3 and GCC. You need to name the toolchain you're using, which would have provided the DEFAULT_ISR_HANDLER code you posted and you need to name the specific hardware, including the specific CPU chip, that the toolchain is targeting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

Just define a C function with the `void SRC_IRQHandler(void)` signature and since the macro is defining the default handler as weak, your function will override the default handler in the linking stage.

There should be a place in your project where `SRC_IRQHandler` is placed in what is called a Vector Table in the Cortex-M3 architecture. You can replace the name of this function with your own C function and your function will be called when this interrupt (exception) happens.

Comment: I am reading this [tutorial](https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/writing-your-own-startup-code-for-cortex-m) and what you are explaining is making a lot of sense to me now. I will try this in the morning. Kudos to you.

Comment: I can confirm that this works pretty well. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The cortex-m family in general has well more than 16 exceptions there are those plus as many interrupts are implemented by that core, 32, 64, 128, 256.  But it is all fundamentally the same.  The way the cortex-m family works is they perform the EABI call for you if you will, they preserve some of the registers and then start execution at the address called out in the vector table done in such a way that you can have the address of a normally compiled C function directly in the table.  Historically you needed to wrap that function with some code to preserve and restore the state and often instruction sets have a special return from interrupt, but the cortex-m they did a bit different.

so knowing that then the next question is how do you get that address in the table, and that depends on your code, build system, etc.  Those handlers might be setup to point to an address in ram and maybe you are running on an RTOS and there is a function you call runtime to register a function for an exception then the RTOS changes the code or some data value in ram that is tied into their handler which essentially wraps around yours.  or you are making the vector table in assembly or some other tool specific thing (although assembly is there, works and easy) and you simply count down the right number of entries (or add a hundred more entries so you can count down to the right entry) and place the name of your C function.

good idea to disassemble or do some other check on the result before running to double check that you have placed the handler address at the right physical address for that interrupt/exception.